# Accent circonflexe sur « mû »

Tags: étymologie, diacritiques

Le participe passé du verbe *mouvoir* s'écrit avec un accent circonflexe. D'où vient-il ?

Les autres verbes du 3e groupe en -oir/-oire n'en ont pas (*pu*, *plu*, *cru*, *bu*, ...). Celui de *mûrir* sert à faire la différence entre *mûr* et *mur*, comme *cru* et *crû* (*croire* et *croître*). Mais je ne trouve pas de raison valable pour *mû*.

Quelle est l'origine de cet accent ? Est-ce qu'il modifiait la prononciation à une époque ? Est-ce qu'il servait à éviter la confusion avec un mot maintenant disparu ?

---

On peut noter que l'Académie Française a remarqué ce manque de cohérence dans le rapport de 1990 :

> Il n’est pas constant à l’intérieur d’une même famille [...] ni même dans la
> conjugaison de certains verbes (*être*, *êtes*, *était*, *étant*).
> De sorte que des mots dont l’histoire est tout à fait
> parallèle sont traités différemment : *mû*, mais *su*, *tu*, *vu*, etc.; *plaît*, mais *tait*.

Et recommande de ne plus accentuer le *u* :

> On conserve l’accent circonflexe sur
> *a*, *e*, et *o*, mais sur *i* et sur *u* il n’est plus obligatoire,
> excepté [...] dans la conjugaison, où il marque une
> terminaison [et] dans les mots où il apporte une distinction de sens
> utile [...].
> Cette mesure entraîne la rectification de certaines
> anomalies étymologiques, en établissant des régularités.
> On écrit désormais *mu* (comme déjà *su*, *tu*, *vu*, *lu*), *plait*
> (comme déjà *tait*, *fait*), [...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Une explication se trouve dans la rubrique « prononciation et orthographe » de l'entrée « mouvoir » dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mouvoir). Cet accent proviendrait d'un ancien hiatus.

> part. passé : mû, mue, mus, mues. Noter l'accent circonflexe uniquement au masc. sing. (< anc. hiatus meu); comme dans dû, crû. Comparer avec ému et promu.

En complément, les précisions suivantes se trouvent dans cet article : [Pourquoi des accents circonflexes ?](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/circonflexe.html).

> **Disparition d'autres lettres**
> Outre s, d'autres lettres amuïes ont été représentées par un accent circonflexe. C'est le cas des voyelles en hiatus dont la première ne se prononçait plus ou qui s'était contractée avec la suivante :

> aage → âge ;
> baailler → bâiller ;
> saoul → soûl (les deux orthographes étant admises) ;

> Le cas est fréquent dans des mots où -u est issu d'anciennes diphtongues médiévales ëu /ey/ (le tréma n'est pas écrit à l'origine) venues à se prononcer /y/ mais écrites de manière conservatrice eu. Il faut attendre la fin du XVIIIe siècle pour que la graphie, hésitant entre ëu (le tréma sert aussi, en français, à marquer une voyelle muette), eu ou û, se fixe sur û :
>
> deu → dû (de devoir) ;
> meu → mû (de mouvoir) ;
> creu → crû (de croître)
> seur → sûr ;
> cruement → crûment ;
> meur → mûr.
>
> Certaines formes qui ont été concernées ne prennent plus d'accent aujourd'hui : seü → sû → su (de savoir) ou peu → pû → pu. Pour les verbes, en vertu de l'analogie, les participes passés en -u ne prennent un accent que pour éviter les homographies possibles.